# Cannot find a download source for Nagios NRPE for RHEL6

Tags: linux, redhat, nrpe

I need to install Nagios NRPE on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.0, but every guide I've found so far describes compiling it from source. This system does not have `gcc` installed and it is firewalled such that it cannot access the package repositories needed to install `gcc` via yum. Is there some place I can download the NRPE package manually?

Comment: Are you sure it is a firewall restricting access or have you not registered/licensed this system? The current release of RHEL is 6.3, so if you're running 6.0 you are woefully behind on patches. For licensing reasons you'll have to register this system either with the RedHat Network or a local Satellite to get updates or install packages not on the install media. Have you done this?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. This shithole i work in has some weird rules bout security, this server machine i need to install nrpe on, can be only accessed from my machine and few others, it cant access basically anything, even other servers in dmz.

Comment: While I strongly encourage tight access restrictions, segmentation, restricting compiler toolchains on production systems, and validating patches before rolling them out, the fact still remains that running EL6.0 *is* a security risk. If you can't update it then you got problems, yo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find NRPE and many other Nagios-related packages in the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), which is practically a must-have for most RHEL/CentOS systems.

If you can't install standard software on the system, you need to have a long chat with whoever is running the network/firewall about why not.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. Please, bare with me. this EPEL repository has compiled NRPE stuff, right? Unfortunately, i can't have a chat with those guys.

Comment: Yes, EPEL has nagios, nrpe, and dozens of nagios plugins.